# Alight 1 item of header to right using only custom.ccs in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, position

I would like just align the facebook image in my header to right.
I only have access to wp-admin and can use a custom.css to do this.

Link to my site : http://test.projekt-tenis.pl/wordpress/

My header just look like :
[image]

And all I want to do is set position of just the facebook image to right with padding 60px like my logo:

To do this  I'm using google :[image]

But I can't find solution to place this facebook button on the right in this container. Can someone help with that? When I try to change the code my whole menu always changes position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last-child of the menu (the last `li`) using CSS and float it right.  Put these lines in your custom.css.

```
/* nth-last-child "-n" means to start from the end, "+3" mean until 3rd from the end. */
.primary-menu li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
```

You will, obviously, have to make sure how that works when resizing the browser.

**Edit**: Even better would be to do as I suggest in the comments and add a class to the menu elements you want on the right-hand side:

1. Go to the Appearance > Menus page in WordPress admin
2. Click "Screen Options" at the top right
3. Make sure "CSS Classes" is checked
4. Expand the menu item you want to float right
5. Enter a class in the "CSS Classes (optional)" field (example: `menu-right`).

Then in your css:

```
.primary-menu li.menu-right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
```

Comment: But when i had 2 images and want to both to the same.  How can i do that? I edited my page and now have 2  facebook images can you check  ?

Comment: I updated the code.  An even better method would be to use the classes in WordPress menu.

Comment: I'll check it tommorrow and reaply accept :) thanks anyway

Comment: Ok i understand but when i want now to put 3 items at the right of site and i try : .primary-menu li:last-child, .primary-menu li:nth-last-child(3) {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
} . This doesn't work to move 3 items to the right can you tell me how it works? and what should i to do to move this 3 images to right?

Comment: You can use: `.primary-menu li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {float: right;}`.  I've updated my answer.